# My textbook sets $\ln \left\{ 1 + \left[ \frac{L}{L_0} - 1 \right] \right\}$ equal to $\frac{L}{L_0} - 1 $. What's the justification for this?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, approximations

Sat to study physics.  I started to study this new chapter Heat and Thermodynamics. It included these steps:
$$
\int_{L_0}^L \frac{dL}{L} = \int_{\theta_0}^\theta \alpha d \theta;  \text{ or } \ln \left[ \frac{L}{L_0} \right] = \alpha \Delta \theta
$$
(where $\Delta \theta = \theta - \theta_0$)
$$
\text{or } \ln \left\{ 1 + \left[ \frac{L}{L_0} - 1 \right] \right\} = \alpha \Delta \theta \qquad \text{or} \qquad \frac{L}{L_0} - 1  = \alpha \Delta \theta
$$

This deduction they made is intriguing me. What do they mean by this? Does natural log have such a property?

Comment: $\ln(1+x) = x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots$ so if $x \ll 1$ we get the approximation $\ln(1+x) \approx x$

Comment: Alternatively, if $L$ is close to $L_0$, then $\displaystyle \int_{L_0}^L dL = \int_{\theta_0}^\theta L \alpha d\theta \approx  \int_{\theta_0}^\theta L_0 \alpha d\theta,$ and so $L - L_0 \approx L_0 \alpha \Delta \theta$ without introducing logs at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The equation is using the approximation $\ln(1 + x) \approx x$, which is the first term of the Taylor series of $f(x) = \ln (1 + x)$:
$$
\ln(1 + x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \dots.
$$
If $x$ is small much less than 1, then all of the terms except the first will be negligible.